# Brand new BaoFeng BF-F8HP -- how to save settings in a channel memory?

Tags: baofeng, equipment-operation, radio-programming

I just got this new 2m/70cm hand-held, and I'm working through programming the local repeaters into channels.  I've been able to set the repeater frequency in VFO mode, then save the settings to channel memories -- except that the offset doesn't save, even if I delete the channel, set the offset, and then re-save the channel.

I've gone through the manual twice, and viewed the video linked in one of the answers below (which effectively mirrored what I had been doing, except I had voice on so could hear "Receiving Memory" and "Transmitting Memory" when saving a channel in Frequency Mode -- I don't see the "scan" button doing anything) -- yet every time I return to Channel Mode, the offset value is set to zero.

This happens regardless whether my band is set to UHF or VHF or whether that setting matches the actual frequency; regardless whether CTCSS is programmed for transmit or receive, and so forth.

I've found comments on a blog post suggesting this model and the very similar UV-5R have a firmware bug that does this.  Is there a known work-around to keep the offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for this online.

Apparently there's a bug in the firmware of the various BaoFeng handie-talkie models (UV-5R family, BF-F8HP, and others) that causes frequency offset to revert to zero when in channel mode, regardless what was saved in any channel memory.

I found [this online document](http://wc5c.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Manually-Programming-BaoFeng-HT-Radio-Channels.pdf) that gives the work around for it:

One must program in Frequency Mode (VFO), preferably with Voice active.  One must delete the channel before saving (you can skip this if programming a previously unused or blank channel).  Program the radio's receive frequqency (the repeater's transmit frequency), offset off, set the correct transmit CTCSS/PL tone, and save the channel; radio will respond "Receiving Memory."

Exit menus, change displayed frequency to the repeater's receive frequency (manually add or subtract the correct offset, if this isn't supplied explicitly), changing no other settings.  Save the same channel again; radio will respond "Transmitting Memory."  You're done, that channel will work correctly when in channel mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on manually programming the radio, this 10-minute [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF38uLNKTkM) should help. The programming description begins about 4:20 into the video, but I recommend watching the introductory material because it affects the programming steps.

Note an error in the voice over at 7:46. The author says, "Hit memory one more time," but he actually presses the MENU button.

Purchasing the [PC-03 programming cable](https://baofengtech.com/Programming-cable) and downloading the [CHIRP software](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home) will dramatically improve the ease and management of programming.

Comment: CHIRP already installed, cable should be waiting for me at home by now.  FWIW, I found and followed online instructions, which seem to have revealed bugs in the radio's firmware, preventing saving certain items when programming manually.

Comment: Aaand -- though CHIRP is native to Linux, apparently the cable I received isn't compatible with Linux.  I'm off to watch that video, so I can at least program the repeaters nearest my home and those I'll pass on my way to work.

Comment: Edited question after viewing the video and trying his method (spoiler: still didn't work).

Comment: Oh, and forgot to mention -- the programming cable I got doesn't work, even after I convinved Ubuntu to talk to it.  "Unexpected response from radio", says CHIRP.

Comment: that sounds more like a configuration error than a broken cable

Comment: try it, reproduce the error. There should be a "debug.log" file in your home directory/.chirp/debug.log. What is the last "Unexpected response, got this:" line?

Comment: @ZeissIkon What Brian said! ^^ The interface cable is always suspect if you did not buy it directly from Baofeng. I found that out the hard way. (BTW, I'm also using Linux).

Comment: @MarcusMüller That occurred when running CHIRP as superuser (wouldn't open the port without added privileges).  Where would I find superuser's CHIRP logs?

Comment: um, don't run CHIRP as superuser; that's a recipe for problems, and I really can't rule out you running as superuser causing the "Unexpected response" issue. CHIRP's website explains how you can give your normal user the privileges required to work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Running as regular user gave "permission denied: cannot open port" type message, even though the machine was able to recognize the presence of usb0 port.  That led me to think opening the USB port for communication required upgraded privileges.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Problem on hold, I've returned the 3rd party cable and ordered a genuine BaoFeng PC-03, we'll see if that behaves differently.

Comment: @MarcusMüller BTech supplied PC-03 cable, newest version of CHIRP from the PPA, and adding my user to the "dialout" group fixed the cable programming,  Manual programming still has the bug with offsets.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Baofeng's VIP software to program independent RX and TX frequencies so you don't have to do it manually for every single one. (I have a BF-F8HP).

https://baofengtech.com/download

(Windows only)

I have Windows 7 (it's an old laptop) so I had to download some drivers for my FTDI USB cable: https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm (I used the Windows* one that was listed first)

Curiously, when I downloaded to the laptop the current radio state on VIP my previously programmed in repeater channels using CHIRP uploaded with correct RX and TX offsets, even though they weren't showing up on the radio before when I switched between normal and reverse mode via the */SCAN key.

I then reuploaded the same settings to the radio and now when I switch between normal and reverse mode (RX freq is shown in normal mode in channel mode, TX freq is shown in reverse mode in channel mode) I see the correct frequency offsets!

The Baofeng VIP software isn't that easy to use and is not translated well, but you can figure it out if you experiment.

Comment: If I'm going to program with software, I'll use CHIRP.  Bao-Feng's program is Windows only, and I'm a Linux user.  And once I got a compatible cable, I did exactly that, radio's been working fine for 18 months.

Comment: Hello Doug, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!